# Need GIT commands since I don't want to risk doing it

Tags: git, github, branch, git-branch

This is what my senior mailed me. 
Due to the merge issue on remote ‘develop’ branch. After new release, I deleted the old ‘develop’ branch from remote and create a new one from ‘master’ branch. **If you have a local develop branch, please delete local branch and it’s remote tracking branch, BUT NOT REMOTE BRANCH.** Please google how to do it if you are not confident.

I need to know what I do is correct. I don't have much experience with GIT.

I will do the following :

1. Delete local branch - I will use the command

   ```
   git checkout develop
   git branch -d feature/login
   ```
2. Delete remote tracking branch but not REMOTE branch.

   ```
   git branch -d -r origin/develop
   ```

   (This will not delete the branch on the remote repo!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should do the following:

- synchronize your copy of the remote repository

  ```
  git fetch
  ```

  <sup>Updates `origin/develop`</sup>
- change to your local `develop` branch

  ```
  git checkout develop
  ```
- take over the remote `develop` to your own

  ```
  git reset origin/develop --hard
  ```
- delete the feature branch

  ```
  git branch -d feature/login
  ```

---

You should **not** delete `origin/develop`.